# Will two external displays harm my Mid 2015 MacBook Pro's integrated graphic card?

Tags: macbook-pro, display

Will connecting two external displays on my MacBook Pro Retina (Mid 2015) with an Intel Iris Pro 1536 MB harm my MacBook graphic card?

The only use that I need is for programming (C++, Java, Python). So, I wonder if it is going to shorten it's lifespan or something like that? One monitor would be connected via DP and other via HDMI or also via DP. Both monitors are 24" 1080p.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Your [MacBook Pro](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP719?locale=en_US) is designed to work with multiple external monitors.

Of course the graphics card needs to push more pixels, therefore getting hotter. But your MacBook will speed up its fans appropriately to ensure proper cooling, so go ahead and enjoy your monitors.